# Joomla и длинные ссылки

Tags: joomla

на сайте везде идут такие длинные ссылки:

> /using-joomla/extensions/components/content-component/article-category-list/8-stellaj

но при этом работает и такая ссылка, без этих лишних строк

> /8-stellaj

как в joomla 2.5 убрать эту фигню? /using-joomla/extensions/components/content-component/article-category-list/

спасибо.

Comment: может сделать тогда rewriterule подскажите только как правильно?)

Comment: RewriteRule ^using-joomla/extensions/components/content-component/article-category-list/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Сделал так, помогает... но физически ссылки материала формируются длинные... может кто знает еще как вправить мозг на физическом уровне?

Answer (score 1):

seo компонент любой поставить

Comment: если ссылка работает и так и так, значит нужно вправить мозг и обойтись без сео компонентов.